# User Engagement Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, instagram, analytics

I am developing a website where one function allows the user to get a rough user engagement score based on the likes and comments on their last 100 posts.

What I have done is take average likes and comments from the last 100 posts and create a ratio.

What I want to do is take into account the total followers a user has and take  ratio, apply it to the like and comment ratio and express that number as a score (0 - 100)

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Well to add the number of followers to your index you need to get the maximum possible follower count. Otherwise you got no maximum value to rely on.

Comment: Wouldn't the number of followers also influence the number of comments and likes, and therefor already be taken into account?

Comment: Yes, that's why I want the engagement represented as a flat score (0 - 100)

Comment: @PhilippBraun you mean I would need to set tiers? such as 0 - 5000, 5000-10000? etc?